# Determine probabilites based on an array python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, probability

Let's say I have and array.shape = (296,3)

Where the first column contains 0 or 1, the second column contains 0,1 or 2 and the final column contains also 0,1 or 2.

I want to know how I can calculate all the probabilities for each one of the 18 possible combinations (2x3x3) of the 3 columns. Possible sequences are [0,0,0];[0,0,1];etc... .

Comment: Add pandas or numpy (I don't remember which one is for probabilities) or another library tag you're using, you should have more answer

Comment: this is a math related problem

Comment: @KavinduRavishka it ins't. The math here is to calculate probabilites. The ideia of the question was to know a way that I can develop an algorithm without needing to count the possibilites 1 by one.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "calculate all the probabilities". How does this have anything to do with probability at all? Where is the source of randomness, in the first place? Please try to show exactly what should happen, for an input that is small enough to work out the answer by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.unique` to collect the unique sequences, along with their `counts`.

```
>>> (unique, counts) = numpy.unique(data, return_counts=True, axis=0)
>>> unique
array([0, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 2],
      [1, 1, 1],
       ...])
>>> counts
array([2, 2, 1, ...])
```

Therefore the probability of the i-th element from `uniques` is its corresponding value from `counts` over the number of rows from your original data. In other words for example a count of `28` over `296` rows would be a probability of ~9.46%.